# Is "for example" a conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions

The following sentence is what I am going to write into my thesis,

> Considering the limitation of the problem, for example, a central
>   robot is necessary to do something and it has to be aware of a number,
>   we introduce the concept of mobility.

I just wonder if there are any grammatical errors here. Is it correct to use "for example" here as a conjunction and add a sentence after it as an example?

Comment: All the comments have been purged. [Comments are for](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) clarifying the question, not for attempting to answer it. Also, [Be Nice](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). If someone is not being nice, flag it for a moderator instead of engaging in back and forth comments with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this [webpage](http://www.myenglishteacher.net/forexample.html) about the usage of 'for example', I think my sentence posted above is incorrect. So I modify it to:

> There are some limitations of the problem. For example, a central
>   robot is necessary to do something and it has to be aware of a number.
>   Therefore, we introduce the concept of mobility.

Comment: A "problem" is usually already a "limitation." Your second two sentences are pretty good, now, but "limitations to the problem" is odd. If you "limit" a "problem," you actually make a situation better. Normally, you would talk about limitations to a solution of some kind.